# Tensorflow API Speed

Tags: python

I have been experimenting with the image classification and object detection APIs and so far the speed of the classification is very slow something like 1.2 seconds which may seem fast but to detect objects in real time in a production setting I need to be much faster. I’m using the NVIDIA 1080 TI and have retrained the model and perhaps the problem is in using the standard code and I need to modify the script.

Comment: As we don't have much information about your code setup, I'm gonna ask a generic question : Is your code optimized to use your multiple GPU cores?

Comment: I have installed and trained using the Tensorflow GPU install which it shows the app is using that for training. The code we’re using is just the standard script available to everyone on the Tensorflow Object Detection github download. This would be label_image.py and object_detection.py